# C++ sizeof(struct)

Tags: c++11

code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  struct{
     unsigned char a:4;
     unsigned char b:4;
  }i;

  struct{
     unsigned char a:4;
     unsigned char b:4;
     unsigned char c:4;
  }j;

  i.a = 1;
  i.b = 1;
  j.a = 1;
  j.b = 1;
  j.c = 1;
  printf("size of i is: %d, size of j is: %d", sizeof(i), sizeof(j));
  return 0;
}
```

why the output is 1 2? means size of i possess 1 byte, j possess 2 bytes. we know unsigned char have 1 byte, so why i not equal 2? i am sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variables in C++ are padded upto next byte.
In struct `i`, both `a` and `b` are of 4 bit summing up to 1 byte.

In `j`, variables sum up to 12 bits, but size is 2 byte due to padding.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/51911/